# The value of get_local_id(0)

Tags: opencl

This is a part of my kernel code:

```
const int2 cord;
cord.x = get_global_id(0);
if(cord.x == 13) 
{
    printf("get_local_id(0) = %d\n", get_local_id(0));
    printf("%d get_local_id(0) = %d\n", 1337, get_local_id(0));
}
```

Which prints

```
get_local_id(0) = 13
1337 get_local_id(0) = 0
```

Why does the second `pritnf` print `0` ?

Comment: Does it change if you cast arguments to printf to int? `printf("%d get_local_id(0) = %d\n", (int) 1337, (int) get_local_id(0));`

Comment: Yes, then it works.

Comment: There's your answer. It's because the byte size of your parameters don't align with the format specifiers/